# C++ WinSock sending commands to telnet server

Tags: c++, telnet, winsock

So I'm making a C++ program that connects through telnet. The connection seems to be working, because I get output from the server. The problem is that I need to send a specific command to telnet. For example a command:

> login user password

Just sending it via send() doesn't seem to do anything (or maybe I'm doing something wrong, but don't see it).
There are some information on the page ftp://ftp.rfc-editor.org/in-notes/rfc854.txt but I don't really understand it.

Can someone show me on an example and explain how should I do it to make it work? Tried to google but I didn't really find exactly what I want. I literally need it to send two commands.

Here's what I have tried (not the full code):

```
int main() {
  int iR;
  std::string input;
  std::cout << "Telnet ip: ";
  std::getline(std::cin, input);
  std::cout << std::endl;

  u_long ip = 0;
  u_short port = DEFAULT_PORT;
  u_long * ptr = &ip

  const char * cptr = input.c_str();
  inet_pton(AF_INET, cptr, ptr);

  std::cout << "Telnet port: ";
  std::getline(std::cin, input);
  std::cout << std::endl;
  iR = std::stoi(input);
  if((iR > SHRT_MAX) || (iR < 0)) {
    std::cout << "Wrong port number, using default." << std::endl;
  }
  else {
    port = iR;
  }

  WSADATA wsaData;
  iR = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
  if (iR != 0) { return 1; }
  SOCKET server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  if (server == INVALID_SOCKET) { WSACleanup(); return 1; }

  sockaddr_in addr;
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = ip;
  addr.sin_port = htons(port);

  std::string user;
  std::string pass;
  std::cout << "Username: ";
  std::getline(std::cin, user);
  std::cout << std::endl; << "Password: ";
  std::getline(std::cin, pass);
  std::cout << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Connecting..." << std::endl;
  if ((connect(server, (SOCKADDR *)&addr, sizeof(addr))) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    std::cout << "Couldn't connect. << std::endl;
    WSAcleanup();
    Sleep(2000);
    return 0;
  }

  int bRecv = 0;
  char buff[2048];

  bRecv = recv(server, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
  if ((bRecv == SOCKET_ERROR) || (bRecv == 0)) {
    std::cout << "Disconnected from the server." << std::endl;
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
  }

  buff[bRecv] = 0;
  // When it connects successfully, a message appears on the screen from server
  std::cout << buff << std::endl;

  memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
  std::string command = "login ";
  command.append(user);
  command.append(" ");
  command.append(pass);

  cptr = login.c_str();
  strcpy_s(buff, cptr);

  iR = send(server, buff, (u_int)strlen(buff), 0);
  if (iR == SOCKET_ERROR) { std::cout << "Couldn't send data." << std::endl; WSACleanup(); return 0;
  while (true) {
    bRecv = recv(server, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
    if ((bRecv == SOCKET_ERROR) || (bRecv === 0)) {
      std::cout << "Disconnected from the server." << std::endl;
      break;
    }
    buff[bRecv] = 0;
    std::cout << buff << std::endl;
  }
  WSACleanup();
  return 0;
}
```

I mean I hope I'm not doing this the wrong way. I'm pretty much a begginer in C++.

Comment: Where are you finding a Telnet server to connect to in 2017? They're about as extinct as Gopher servers.

Comment: telnet commands should end with \r\n. I do not see you doing so.

Comment: @tadman ts3 query

Comment: @SergeyA You're a savior. Thank you.

Comment: @tadman Telnet is not extinct at all -- try telnetting to google.com, port 80 for example.

Comment: @MrEricSir That's not a telnet service, it's a TCP socket. Just because the `telnet` client can interface with it does not make it a service that conforms to the [Telnet RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc854). Telnet as a service running on port 23 is extremely rare to see except on honey pot systems. The `telnet` client is far from useless, though [Netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) is often a better solution if it's available.

Comment: @tadman I think NASA is still using telnet for their JPL Horizons server. That would be one such example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending a line break after your command.

```
std::string command = "login ";
command.append(user);
command.append(" ");
command.append(pass);
command.append("\r\n"); // <-- add this
```

You also do not need to use `buff` to hold the command, you can send `command` directly:

```
iR = send(server, command.c_str(), (u_int) command.length(), 0);
```

Comment: That works, thank you. Didn't think it would be that simple.

Comment: @GorudoYami hi. can you help me fixing mine? telnet server wont execute my command http://codepad.org/y0m71GEL

Comment: @Remy Lebeau can you help me too?

Comment: @LorenceHernandez "*help me too*" - this is not how this site works. If you want help, please post a new question, providing your code (don't post it on an external site), and explaining what you are trying to accomplish and what is not working for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48144436/telnet-server-wont-execute-my-command-sent-from-a-socket